# "The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'."

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public partial class Address : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

   string query;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


           con.Open();
           query = "select [Addid] from Address";
           int i=1;
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           DataTable dtab = new DataTable();
          da.Fill(ds);
          txtaddid.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

          if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
          txtaddid.Text = "Add" + i;

       else 
              if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)

       {

            int id = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 1;
             txtaddid.Text = "Add" + id;
        }

  con.Close();

       }
```

what i want to do is retrieve the data from the addid column  in the address table to text box when ever the pageloads

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);`

Comment: [Google returns](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q="The+SelectCommand+property+has+not+been+initialized) `15.7k` result. Search your error or exception message in Google first.

Answer (score 3):

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
```

change to

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```